# Error when install Coqui TTS in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, text-to-speech, pyproject.toml, coqui

When I use: `!pip install TTS`   in google colab, to install Coqui TTS, I get this error:

```
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  error: **subprocess-exited-with-error**
  
  × Preparing metadata (**pyproject.toml**) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

[image: screenshot of error]. This is my [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P9LFK-Icjk5sc3gQvPCw0IaMA4FwwsHz?usp=sharing). I see, version of python in google colab: **Python 3.10.12**
It was running successfully 2 days ago.

Comment: There is already a [bug report](https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS/issues/2986) about this on their repository.